# How can I display an image + text in navbar-brand Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need an image alongside some text on my navbar-brand. I've tried to achieve that some times but with no success.

How to do it without "hacking" bootstrap?

Here's my code:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <section class="container">
            <section class="navbar-header">
                <a ui-sref="home" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img id="logo" class="d-inline-block mr-1" alt="Logo" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137380/isolated/lists/1b2ca367caa7eff8b45c09ec09b44c16-instagram-icon-logo.png">
                    <span class="align-text-bottom">InstaClone!</span>
                </a>
            </section>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="chat">Chat</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 try like this

```css
img#logo{width:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" class="d-inline-block mr-1" alt="Logo" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137380/isolated/lists/1b2ca367caa7eff8b45c09ec09b44c16-instagram-icon-logo.png"> <span>InstaClone!</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="chat">Chat</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That kind worked. I just didn't realize it wasn't a bad practice. Thanks!